# Remove href attribute if value is null in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, attributes

I am trying to apply a condition to href or ng-href.

The condition is `if email !== null`

My code looks like this:

```
<a ng-attr-href="{{email !== null}}" href="mailto:{{email | lowercase}}">{{email | lowercase | nullValue}}</a>
```

This is evaluating to either `href="true"` or `href="false"`.

This seems close to working, but I still get the href attribute being there if the value is null:

```
ng-attr-href="mailto:{{email !== null ? email: email | lowercase}}"
```

How do I remove the href entirely if the value from the data is null? Is it possible to wrap the entire condition around the html href attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways of solving your problem. I prefer this:

```
<a ng-if="email !== null" href="mailto:{{email | lowercase}}">{{email | lowercase | nullValue}}</a>
<a ng-if="email == null">{{email | lowercase | nullValue}}</a>
```

You can easily wrap this into a *directive* if you need more complex conditions or attribute toggles.

Comment: Brilliant. I think ng-if makes alot more sense to me. Thanks.

Comment: Easy and nice solution

Answer (score 2):

You can also use something similar to your *ng-attr-href* as before but instead with only *ng-href* :

```
<a ng-href="{{email ? 'mailto:'+(email | lowercase) : ''}}">
{{email | lowercase | nullValue}}
</a>
```

While this would always create the *ng-href* attribute in the anchor tag, without an email it would be empty and would not create the *href* attribute.  The end results would look like the following:

```
<a ng-href="mailto:tests" href="mailto:tests">tests</a>
<a ng-href></a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. This code looks like it will work, and makes sense in terms of using a ternary operator, unfortunately I was working on that application nearly a year ago, so it's already been released to production.

Comment: No problem, I was looking for ways to do the same and I thought I'd add an option for people also searching.

Comment: Actually out of interest I did try it on an old jsfiddle, but I think there is an issue with your concatenation, it seems to return an error for me. Is your code definitely working? Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/7cft0e43/21/ I tried it with various joins and splits and without the lowercase filter.

Comment: Looks like your fiddle is using angularjs 1.0.3 which didn't allow for the **?:** syntax.  I bumped up your fiddle's angularjs version to 1.2.1 and all is working.  I hope I didn't overlook a version requirement for your original project, 1.2.1 should have been well released at that time.